# download simultaneously while displaying in pdf format

Tags: php

My intention is to convert a total php page into html, and subsequently convert the html to pdf and render it through the browser.Which is done , apart from that while showing it on the browser , **it will simultaneously download the pdf automatically which is not happening**.
Its with PHP.

Can to tell me the basic concept ..as to how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either you show the PDF in the browser OR you download it to the hard disk. Can't do both (unless you generate it twice, that is).

Comment: You need to simplify and make this question clearer. Are you trying to render a HTML page and then at the same time have that page available as PDF download? If so, you need to do this in two requests, render HTML, fireoff an AJAX request to push a pdf download to use.

Answer (score 1):

You already render the page in the browser.  Before displaying the page, `header()` the user to the location which will serve the same page as an attachment, but do not `exit`.  This will allow them to download the file, but it will still load the file on the page.  Not 100% sure that this will work, but it's worth a shot.

BTW different browsers will handle pdfs differently and depending on settings, plugins, etc.  For instance, some might try to download the file anyway instead of showing it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look over the question again. As I read it, you're asking how to display something that hasn't yet been downloaded (*while* it's downloading), and that is obviously not possible and so cannot be what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a header, which tells the browser what to do when it receives the file.

```
<?php 
  header("Content-Type: $filedatatype" ); 
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $FileObject->name . "\";"); 
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:­ binary"); 
  header("Content-Length: " . $filesize);
?>
```